# VBA used save range as input for diagramm

Tags: vba, excel

after a match operation in VBA - I get a range variable

```
 Set rngSel = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, 28).Offset(0, startIdx - 1), Cells(3, 28).Offset(0, endIdx - 1))
```

It tells me that the data that I want to visualise in a bar chart are between A3 and Z3 (always in a single row) , fo r instance. I can also print this

```
 MsgBox ("rngSel=" & rngSel.Cells.Address)
```

However, now I would like to use rngSel to feed the input for my diagramm. I tried

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Diagramm 1").rngSel
```

That does not work however. rngSel only provides the x coordinates range (A3 to Z3, for instance. The y values are in A4 to Z4. How can I - based on the rngSel object tell my Diagramm 1 to only take the data from 
A3:Z4? Without manually specifying but dynamically using rngSel?

whole macro

```
Sub Aku()
    Dim startIdx As Integer, endIdx As Integer
    Set valRng = ActiveSheet.Range("AB3:LS3")

    startIdx = Application.Match(CLng(Cells(2, 18).Value), valRng, 0)
    endIdx = Application.Match(CLng(Cells(2, 22).Value), valRng, 0)

    Set rngSel = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, 28).Offset(0, startIdx - 1), Cells(3, 28).Offset(0, endIdx - 1))

    MsgBox ("rngSel=" & rngSel.Cells.Address)
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=rngSel.Resize(2), PlotBy:=xlRows


End Sub
```

Comment: just rngsel will do it. or ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Diagramm 1").range(rngSel.address)

Comment: Not sure to get you but may be "rngSel.Resize(2)" is what you're after

Comment: So - I have a range stored in rngSel that is from A3 to Z3 - the chart source should however be a3 to z4 - If I use nathan solution I get a debugging error- could somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

**edited** after further OP's clarifications

try this:

```
Sub Aku()
    Dim startIdx As Integer, endIdx As Integer
    Dim rngSel As Range, valRng As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        Set valRng = .Range("AB3:LS3")

        startIdx = Application.Match(CLng(Cells(2, 18).Value), valRng, 0)
        endIdx = Application.Match(CLng(Cells(2, 22).Value), valRng, 0)

        Set rngSel = .Range(Cells(3, 28).Offset(0, startIdx - 1), Cells(3, 28).Offset(0, endIdx - 1))
    End With
    Worksheets("Sheet 1").ChartObjects("Diagramm 1").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rngSel.Resize(2), PlotBy:=xlRows
End Sub
```

it assumes you're running this macro when the *Active* sheet is the one where to read values from

Comment: there is an error that an object variable or with block variable is missing in the debuggin statement

Comment: shouldnt it be       ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=rngSel.Resize(2,), PlotBy:=xlRows  - but then I cant compile but I want to add a row to the range not a column - ?

Comment: @Sonnecken56, did you get through it?

Comment: so I get the same error again - is the problem that the Diagramm 1 part is not in there? Object variable or block with variable error - again . I pasted my whole macro in the question

Comment: if i do ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Diagramm 1").rngSel.Resize(2) - i get an index out of range error

Comment: what is "Diagramm 1"? What's the name of the Chart?

Comment: Diagramm 1 is the name of the chart which shall be displayed from the data

Comment: the data is in two rows - the rngSel originally captures only the range for the x axis - and i need tot extend it to the y axis (in the row below) and display it in diagramm 1

Comment: somehow the Charts row in the code ist still highlighted with the error index out of range - any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: as per you comments _"Diagramm 1 is the name of the chart which shall be displayed from the data"_. Thus I assumed it is a `Chart` object (a tab by itself) and not an _embedded_ chart in a plain worksheet. Is it correct?

Comment: so:1) what's the name of the sheet it's embedded in? 2) what's the name of the chart itself (or is it the only chart in that sheet)?

Comment: how would the code need to be changed and is there a chance to influence that the y values are displayed as line - not only as dots?

Comment: the name of the sheet is Sheet 1, the name of the chart is Diagramm 1

Comment: see edited answer. if it solves your _original_ question then please mark it as accepted. thank you. as for your _new_ request try doing it manually while recording a macro and see the proper required commands

Comment: okay great - so how would i dictate for the row to be depicted as a line rather than points?

Comment: Please follow my last comment suggestion: record a macro while you set points format. And please mark this answer as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: @Sonnecken56, didn't my my answer solve your _original_ question?

Comment: @Sonnecken56, it'be nice of you giving proper feedback to people trying at helping you. Thank you!